# Microsoft sql error exception

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, exception

```
 try {
        //     con = dbConn.mySqlConnection();
            con = DatabaseConnection.getRAWConnection();
 String insertSqlTable = "insert into certification VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,?)";
          pst = con.prepareStatement(insertSqlTable);
          pst.setInt(1, td.getEmpId());
        pst.setString(2, td.getRname());
        pst.setString(3, td.getStream());
        pst.setString(4, td.getCertificationType());
        pst.setString(5, td.getCertificationName());
        pst.setString(6, td.getCertificationDate());
        //pst.setTimestamp(7, timestamp);
        pst.setInt(7, td.getScore());

        int count = pst.executeUpdate();
        if (count >= 1) {
            con.commit();
            status = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error occured while inserting certification details into database");
            con.rollback();
            status = false;
        }
```

I am getting following exception :

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Operand type clash:
>   int is incompatible with datetime2

Comment: may be the 7th column in your table is not timestamp, show us the table structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
pst.setInt(7, td.getScore());
```

use

```
pst.setInt(8, td.getScore());
```

`7th` argument is already there as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.you are insterested to set `8th` one.

**UPDATE**

try this

```
try {
        //  con = dbConn.mySqlConnection();
            con = DatabaseConnection.getRAWConnection();
 String insertSqlTable = "insert into certification VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(insertSqlTable);
        pst.setInt(1, td.getEmpId());
        pst.setString(2, td.getRname());
        pst.setString(3, td.getStream());
        pst.setString(4, td.getCertificationType());
        pst.setString(5, td.getCertificationName());
        pst.setString(6, td.getCertificationDate());
        java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
        pst.setTimestamp(7, date);
        pst.setInt(8, td.getScore());

        int count = pst.executeUpdate();
        if (count >= 1) {
            con.commit();
            status = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error occured while inserting certification details into database");
            con.rollback();
            status = false;
        }

}
```

Comment: But still I am getting error.It states that index 8 is out of range

Comment: OP is doing the right way, your answer will throw error because there should only be 7 parameters

Answer (score 0):

May be the variable score is of datetime type thats why it is giving this exception, just try to use setTime() of Calender class instead of the setInt().